# How can I read the values of a GraphMolWrap.SWIGTYPE_p_double in .NET?

Tags: .net, f#, swig, rdkit

I am trying to use the cheminformatics library `RDKit` in `.NET` with `F#`, [using this wrapper](https://github.com/kazuyaujihara/build-rdkit). Here is a small sample of code:

```
#r "nuget: RDKit.DotNetWrap"
open GraphMolWrap

let mol = RWMol.MolFromSmiles "COc1cccc(=O)c2cc(F)c(N3CCNCC3)cc21"
let adjMat = mol.getAdjacencyMatrix()
printfn "%A" adjMat

// Output: GraphMolWrap.SWIGTYPE_p_double
```

But I cannot seem to get the individual entries of the matrix. As a simple exercise, if I could convert `adjMat` to a `Seq` of `Seq` of doubles, I could perform my calculations.

How can I unpack the `GraphMolWrap.SWIGTYPE_p_double` to get the individual entries?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to access the entries:

```
let a = Double_Array.frompointer(adjMat)
for i = 0 to 200 do
    printfn "%A" <| a.getitem(i)
```

However, I don't see any way to get the dimensions of the matrix, so I'm not sure if this will be much help to you. You might want to contact the author of build-rdkit for assistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Something is better than nothing, and at least your answer has unblocked me temporarily. I can try to hack something together for the dimensions. If there is no better answer, I will accept this.